Turborepo Namespace Trouble
What is the right way to change the default namespace from @repo. The documentation mentions how it is nice to change namespace to one's organization. I tried doing this by manually renaming @repo across package.json on tsconfi and esconfig, deleting the node_module, rerun npm install and tsc --init.
I kept getting a ModuleBuildError along the lines of "An issue occurred while parsing a tsconfig.json file..."
